# Scattering matrix column by column in MPI using Fortran and contiguous datatype

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I'm trying to generate a matrix full of random numbers, of dimensions `(mysize)x(Np)`, where `Np` is a given number (say,5). `Mysize` comes from the number of processes. And then each processor should take its own column, of size `1xNp`.

My first idea was to create a vector data type but then I realized this can be done by using the contiguous data type. The code runs with no errors, but it prints only some of the numbers that were supposed to be there. I'm quite sure the problem lies on the indicators (`type_column`, `MPI_REAL`, etc.) and how should they actually be but I can't figure this out. Anyone care to help?

The code:

```
program main

    use mpi
    integer :: ierr,myrank,mysize
    integer ::  Np=5, type_column
    integer*8, external :: seedgen
    real*8, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: x_init
    real*8, dimension(:), allocatable :: block_x
    character(4) :: rank
    integer, dimension(1) :: new_seed

    call MPI_INIT(ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myrank,ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,mysize,ierr)

    allocate(block_x(0:Np-1))

    if (myrank==0) then
        allocate(x_init(0:Np-1,0:mysize-1))
        new_seed = seedgen(myrank)
        write(*,*) new_seed !This is to check if the seed changes each time
        call random_seed(put=new_seed)
        call random_number(x_init)
        open(unit=1111, file='./x_tot.txt')
        write(1111,*) x_init
        close(1111) !Up to this point, everything works
    end if

    call MPI_TYPE_CONTIGUOUS(Np,MPI_REAL,type_column,ierr)
    call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(type_column,ierr)
    call MPI_SCATTER(x_init(:,myrank),Np,MPI_REAL,block_x,Np,type_column,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)     

    write(rank,'(I4)') myrank
    write(*,*) 'I, process ',myrank,' received ', block_x(0:Np-1)
    open(unit=myrank, file='./x_teste_'//trim(adjustl(rank))//'.txt')
    write(myrank,*) block_x
    close(myrank)

    call MPI_TYPE_FREE(type_column,ierr)

    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

end program main

!!! You may ignore what is down below, just a function to generate random seeds.

function seedgen(myrank)
    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none
    integer(kind=int64) :: seedgen
    integer, intent(IN) :: myrank
    integer :: s

    call system_clock(s)
    seedgen = abs( mod((s*181)*((myrank-83)*359), 104729) )
end function seedgen
```

The output (after running with 3 processors, thus mysize=3)

```
 I, process            0  received   0.247272870046176     
 0.386432141459887       8.816221414742263E-316  0.000000000000000E+000
 0.000000000000000E+000
 I, process            1  received   2.737792569698344E-008
 I, process            2  received   5.231628354959370E-002
 0.454932876242927       3.330771999738651E-315  0.000000000000000E+000
 0.000000000000000E+000
 3.352416881721526E+270  5.298272496856962E-315  0.000000000000000E+000
 0.000000000000000E+000
```

The matrix x_tot:

```
 0.247272870046176       0.386432141459887       0.473788032900533
 0.239586263133600       0.851724848335892       5.231628354959370E-002
 0.454932876242927       0.702720716936168       0.559915585253771
 0.605745282251549       0.253298270763062       0.809867899324171
 0.590174190311136       0.125210425650182       8.138975171285148E-002
```

So you can see that some numbers are the good ones, the rest is garbage.

Comment: That's a good point. I've changed the type to MPI DOUBLE where it wqs MPI REAL and now by output is almost good, it comes up like this:

 0.172448542741186       0.365799359554864       0.873652885323619
  0.431791120535807       0.736888940276372

So it has 3 rows and 2 columns but it should have only 1 row and 5 columns. Trying to fix it now

Comment: It worked. Thanks again @francescalus

Comment: Please do not add the solution into the question. You can post an answer instead.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot

Comment: for a better readibility, sendbuffer could be `x_init(:,0) instead`. also, if recvtype is `type_column`, then should recvcount be `1` instead of `Np` ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but putting x_init(:,0) would just do it for the processor of rank 0? Notice that it is out of the if clause, so I want each processor to get its own chunk of numbers (thus myrank). As for the recvcount, good question. It works doing my way but I'll try what you said.

Comment: in a scatter, sendbuffer is only relevant on the root rank, which is rank 0 in your case

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thanks for that! I didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MPI_DOUBLE as suggested above and changing the writing as below worked fine. Thanks again

```
open(unit=myrank, file='./x_teste_'//trim(adjustl(rank))//'.txt')
    do i=0,Np-1
        write(myrank,*) block_x(i)
    end do
close(myrank)
```